# Confused because of for loop in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I defined a `used = []` as global `var` in my program. Now I have a function `jimoti` which is in `while Loop`. Inside of the function I'm looping over a results of web-scraping(bs4) and adding a `title` of web-scrape to `used` list. When  the `title` exists in `used` I'm trying to not to print it again, but it prints again and again bacause regex matchs it on two or three keywords, so I'm having the same text 2, 3 times printed. how could I change the code, to print it only once?

Here is the code

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from time import sleep
from random import randint
import re
import os

allowed = ["pc", "FUJITSU", "LIFEBOOK", "win" "Windows",
            "PC", "Linux" "linux", "HP", "hp", "notebook", "desktop",
            "raspberry", "NEC", "mac", "Mac", "Core"]
denied = ["philips"]
used = set()

source = requests.get("https://jmty.jp/aichi/sale-pcp").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')


def jimoti(sk):
    global used
    for h2 in soup.find_all('div', class_='p-item-content-info'):
        title = h2.select_one('.p-item-title').text
        address = h2.select_one('.p-item-title').a["href"]
        price = (h2.select_one('.p-item-most-important').text).replace("円", "").replace("\n", "").replace(",", "")
        price = int(price)
        town = h2.select_one('.p-item-supplementary-info').text
        if price < 5000000 and title not in used:
            used.add(title)
            for pattern in allowed:
                print(pattern)
                if re.search(pattern, title):
                    second(sk, title, address, price, town)
                    break

def second(sk, title, address, price, town):
    sk = sk
    title = title
    address = address
    price = price
    town = town
    for prh in denied:
        print(prh)
        if re.search(prh, title):
            break
        else:
            send(sk, title, address, price, town)
                            


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        jimoti(sk)
        sleep(randint(11,20))
```

Comment: Use a set instead of a list, then duplicates will automatically be removed.

Comment: wow, simple as hell! Thanks :D

Comment: @Barmar tried it that way, but It does the same thing, only this time I inserted `print(type(used))` so it prints `<class 'set'>` after every element - above post edited as you suggested

Comment: Why are you calling `.update()` on a set?  Why not just `.add()`?

Comment: Don't print the word if it's already in the set.

Comment: it does the same thing with `add` and `update`. And when I try to print the `used` outside of loop - in level of that `global used` line, it show that set has a values one by one alphabet

Comment: When you call `used.update("some string")`, it adds each individual character to the set.

Comment: Okay, got it! Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

The original question was about a loop printing an element more then once when a condition is set- we avoid that by `break` out of the loop after the first time we hit it.

```
seen = set()
for i in range(10):
    if i not in seen:
        for x in range(10):
            seen.add(i)
            break
```

There is logic in the middle of your inner loop -

```
for prh in denied:
        print(prh)
        if re.search(prh, title):
            break
        else:
            send(sk, title, address, price, town)
```

This as written will look for `prh` in `title` until it finds it, and then break- so will call send once for each value in `prh` that isn't in `title`. That is probably not the logic you meant- how about `send unless any of the prh values is in title?`

```
if all([prh not in title for prh in denied]):
    send(sk, title, address, price, town)
```

Going up a level, you have basically the same logic for "allowed". My guess is that the correct logic is this-

```
used.add(title)
if (
    any([word in title for word in allowed])
    and all([word not in title for word in denied]
):
  send(sk, title, address, price, town)
```

I'm also not sure why you have those sleeps littered in there, seems destructive. Not sure stackoverflow is the best forum for the level of support you may need- there is a reddit for python beginners that may be more helpful.

Comment: thanks for the comment! I'm trying to send values: `title`, `address`,`price` as one bunch of values to another function inside of loop (which I did not write in the example above) after `print(title, price)` I'm using a `send(title, address, price)` inside of that loop, as a `generator?` for another function, so When I try to insert it to the `set` it may not be very good solution, because I'm not able to send it to the next function one by one

Comment: So if you are trying to just call that function once per value, you would use a `break` statement after the call

Comment: I updated my code above. Im breaking the loop, but this time it sending infinitive times to `send` function, I would like to have it there only once as in set

Comment: you'll actually have to call break twice- notice that there are two loops between your logic and the "is in" test. (as a note, if your code gets to three nested for loops, you should probably start breaking it into functions at a minimum)

Comment: It becomes too confusing, so I rewrote it and break to two functions. as I edited above. This works find when doing a `re.search` only once, but it doubles the values, if I'm doing it the second time in `second` function. How Could I change it please?